# Build static library

Tags: xcode, ios, static, build

I am trying to build a **.a** static library for my iPhone project.

So, I have created a new project, and I used the template `Cocoa Touch Static Library`.

Then, in `XCode 4.0`, I add my **.m** and **.h** files.

i have successfully build the project, but no **.a** file is created In `XCode`, I see **.a** file in `Products` category but displayed in red; so it doesn't exist.

I don't understand why my build button don't create **.a** file, any help?

Comment: This Tutorial is great [how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/), Plus have you checked the bin folder in your project?

Comment: Great link, ti's very helpful ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I see that you accepted the answer, but I thought I'd leave a note for future library developers. After upgrading an Xcode 3.x based static library project to 4.x, the library will not always upgrade and begin doing universal library builds. When this happens, the project build will be successful and apps linked against the target dependency will run fine, but you'll get red static library files showing in the projects you pull in. This is very annoying and the only fix I have found is to recreate the project files -- I tried auditing the build settings but was unable to figure out the confounding factors.

Hope this helps save somebody the 2 hours I just lost :-P

Comment: It may work to remove the red .a nodes from the project structure, rebuild each static lib targeting "iOS Device" and then re-establish your linker dependencies in project settings (which will recreate the .a nodes -- hopefully in black this time).  This worked for me in at least one project I upgraded (saved me from having to rebuild the project structure from scratch.)